# How to get the playback % progress from a MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to know how far the video had progressed when the user closes the video.

So for I have this:

```
- (void) moviePlayerDidFinsh:(NSNotification*) notification
{
    MPMoviePlayerController* moviePlayer = notification.object;
    NSLog(@"FINISHED duration was:%f", moviePlayer.duration);
}
```

`initialPlaybackTime` and `endPlaybackTime` both seam to be useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a property `currentPlaybackTime` in MPMediaPlayback protocol.

> The current position of the playhead. (required)
>
> @property(nonatomic) NSTimeInterval currentPlaybackTime

% value = currentPlaybackTime/duration;

Answer (score 1):

The property is `currentPlaybackTime` (in seconds).

This is only useful if the `MPMovieFinishReason` is equal to `MPMovieFinishReasonUserExited`.

```
NSDictionary* userInfo = [aNotification userInfo];    
MPMovieFinishReason finishReason = [[userInfo objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey] intValue];
if (finishReason == MPMovieFinishReasonUserExited) {
        NSTimeInterval playbackTime = [moviePlayer currentPlaybackTime];
        // ...
}
```

Comment: no, it's not. I've tried 'MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded'. it also works.